# How can I convert/map a List<Step<? extends LiteElement, ? extends LiteElement>>[] to List<Step<LiteElement, LiteElement>> []?

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

I need to convert  `List<Step<? extends LiteElement, ? extends LiteElement>>[]` to `List<Step<LiteElement, LiteElement>>[]`. I assume this can be done with streams but I have not been able to get it to work.

Something like:

```java
private List<Step<LiteElement, LiteElement>>[] convert(List<Step<? extends LiteElement,? extends LiteElement>>[] stepLists) {
    return Arrays.stream(stepLists)
                 .map(l -> (List<Step<LiteElement, LiteElement>>)l)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
  }
```

Comment: what error message did you get when you tried that?

Comment: Unrelated: mixing generics and arrays is a bad idea. Why are you using an array of Lists, instead just Lists of Lists?

Comment: And for the record, you want to study and understand what `? extends X` means: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20various%20multi-level%20instantiations?

Comment: I took @GhostCat advice and changed my code to use a List of Lists.

Comment: Please see [mcve] . David asked you 2 hours ago to include the error message you get. And as you changed the code to use list of lists, please update the question accordingly.